# Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:3000 When using cluster in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cluster-computing

I have a simple express application. that receives a request, adds a job to a queue using the Bull module, and then sends back the data when done.I am using Heroku as the server.

Reading Heroku docs the way to do it is by using the cluster. I tried to follow the docs but when I run the app I keep getting Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:3000 error.I understand that all the cores are trying to access the same port that's why I'm getting this error.

I'm using the Throng module for clustering.

this is the error message.

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:3000
    at listenOnPrimaryHandle (node:net:1397:18)
    at shared (node:internal/cluster/child:149:3)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (node:internal/cluster/child:106:7)
    at process.onInternalMessage (node:internal/cluster/utils:49:5)
    at process.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:938:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at listenOnPrimaryHandle (node:net:1398:21)
    at shared (node:internal/cluster/child:149:3)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  errno: -4091,
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: null,
  port: 3000
}
```

and this is my index.js code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Queue = require('bull')
const throng = require('throng')
const {getScrapedTikTokData} = require('./local')
const {Webhook} = require('discord-webhook-node')
const hook = new Webhook(process.env.WEBHOOK_CHANNEL || '')

// Initialize BULL
const REDIS_URL = process.env.REDIS_URL || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
const workQueue = new Queue('work', REDIS_URL, {
    defaultJobOptions: {
        removeOnComplete: true,
        removeOnFail: true
    }
})
const workers = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1
const maxJobsPerWorker = 50


app.get('/discord', async (req, res) => {
    const url = req.query.url
    console.log(url)
    let job = await workQueue.add({url: url})
    res.json({id: job.id})
})

function start() {
    const workQueue = new Queue('work', REDIS_URL)

    workQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, async job => {
        const url = job.data.url
        console.log(url)
        await getScrapedTikTokData(url)
        return {value: 'working'}
    })
}

workQueue.on('global:completed', async (jobId, result) => {
    console.log(`Job completed with result ${result}`)
    try {
        await hook.send(result)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('App is running...')
})

throng({workers, start})
```

Comment: The only place 3000 appears in the code you've shared here is in the `app.listen()` call, and it will only be used if `process.env.PORT` is falsy. Are you using a `Procfile`? Have you declared your application as a `web` process, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Chris, I do have procfile. declaring the application as a web process, tho I'm trying to run it locally. before I push it to Heroku. if i comment the last line, the throng function. the sever runs.